# SQL Procedure (Sybase Advantage Database Server)

Tags: sql, sybase

I have table contain below data:

```
EMPCODE  PAYCODE  AMOUNT
------------------------
001      A        100
001      B        200
002      A        120
002      C         80
003      B         50
003      D         20
```

All PAYCODE in table at the moment are A, B, C, D.

However, other EMPCODE with other new  PAYCODE such as E or F, might be added in later on.

- EMPCODE 001 has PAYCODE A and B (he doesn't have PAYCODE C and D).
- EMPCODE 002 has PAYCODE A and C (he doesn't have PAYCODE B and D).
- EMPCODE 003 has PAYCODE B and D (he doesn't have PAYCODE A and C).

I want to create a simple stored procedure / SQL which can add the dummy records for each EMPCODE for PAYCODE which they don't own.

My expected result as below:

```
EMPCODE  PAYCODE  AMOUNT
------------------------
001      A        100
001      B        200
001      C          0
001      D          0
002      A        120
002      B          0
002      C         80
002      D          0
003      A          0
003      B         50
003      C          0
003      D         20
```

I can achieve that through coding but I need to do it via a stored procedure.

Is there any SQL stored procedure to achieve this?

Appreciate for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Join` to get the result. **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88afb/2)**

```
SELECT C.EMPCODE, C.PAYCODE, ISNULL(D.AMOUNT, 0) AS AMOUNT FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT EMPcode from Test GROUP BY EMPCODE) AS A,
        (SELECT Paycode FROM Test GROUP BY PAYCODE) AS B
) AS C
LEFT JOIN Test AS D
ON C.EMPCODE=D.EMPCODE AND C.PAYCODE = D.PAYCODE
```

**UPDATE:**

1) To get the `distinct EMPCODE` from table

```
(SELECT EMPcode from Test GROUP BY EMPCODE) AS A
```

2) To get the `distinct PAYCODE` from table

```
(SELECT Paycode FROM Test GROUP BY PAYCODE) AS B
```

3) To get the all `PAYCODE` value for each `Empcode`.

```
SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT EMPcode from Test GROUP BY EMPCODE) AS A,
        (SELECT Paycode FROM Test GROUP BY PAYCODE) AS B
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, It's work. But could you explain about:                                             SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT EMPCODE FROM RPTRX GROUP BY EMPCODE) AS A,
        (SELECT PAYCODE FROM RPTRX GROUP BY PAYCODE) AS B

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating all the combinations of `empcode` and `paycode` using a `cross join` in a sub-query that you then use as a derived table for a left join. To not insert already existing rows you should exclude them using a correlated `not exists` predicate. Written as a stored procedure it could look like this:

```
create proc insert_missing_values as 
insert your_table (empcode, paycode, amount)
select distinct codes.empcode, codes.paycode, isnull(your_table.amount, 0) amount 
from (
    select t1.empcode, t2.paycode 
    from your_table t1, your_table t2
    group by t1.empcode, t2.paycode
    ) codes    
left join your_table on 
  codes.empcode = your_table.empcode 
  and 
  codes.paycode = your_table.paycode
where not exists (
    select 1 from your_table 
    where codes.empcode = your_table.empcode and codes.paycode = your_table.paycode
    )
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0aaa6/1)

Edit: as Sybase ASE doesn't support the explicit `cross join` you can use a unqualified implicit join with the same effect by doing `from TableA, TableB` which returns the Cartesian product of rows. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) for an explanation.

Comment: hi jpw, thanks for the answer, but my database engine (Sybase Advantage Database Server 8.1) dont recognize CROSS JOIN

Comment: @btan Oh, I wasn't aware. Actually you can remove the `cross join` keyword to achieve the same effect. I've updated my answer to reflect this.